# Changing Java version in Bazel

Tags: java, macos, bazel

I am using Bazel as the build tool for my Java project. I have JDK 11 installed on my mac, but Bazel uses Java 8 to build the binaries. Does anyone know how I could change this?

Comment: Check the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040291/configuring-bazel-to-build-test-using-a-specific-jvm-version

Answer (score 0):

*BUILD.bazel*

```
java_binary(
    name = 'JavaBinary',
    srcs = ['JavaBinary.java'],
    main_class = 'JavaBinary',
)
load(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:default_java_toolchain.bzl",
    "default_java_toolchain",
)
default_java_toolchain(
  name = "default_toolchain",
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

*JavaBinary.java*

```
public class JavaBinary {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Successfully executed JavaBinary!");
    System.out.println("Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
  }
}
```

*WORKSPACE.bazel*

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_java",
    sha256 = "220b87d8cfabd22d1c6d8e3cdb4249abd4c93dcc152e0667db061fb1b957ee68",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_java/releases/download/0.1.1/rules_java-0.1.1.tar.gz",
)

load("@rules_java//java:repositories.bzl", "rules_java_dependencies", "rules_java_toolchains")

rules_java_dependencies()

rules_java_toolchains()
```

Run it this way:

```
bazel run :JavaBinary \
      --java_toolchain=:default_toolchain \
      --javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11
```

You can also create `.bazelrc` file an then execute `bazel run :JavaBinary`:

*.bazelrc*

```
build --java_toolchain=:default_toolchain
build --javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk11
```