# How to build and run using an up-to-date version of JDK?

Tags: java, bazel

Bazel is downloading and using an old Java 11.0.1.  There have been [*five* releases of Java 11 with security updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11_updates) since then.

I can [make Bazel use my local JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040799) but this has obvious drawbacks.

How can I build using a safe up-to-date version of JDK?

Comment: What obvious drawbacks?   BTW: If Bazel is downloading and installing an out of date Java 11 release, that is a bug in Bazel.  Report it.

Comment: I think that a more accurate statement is that Bazel has an embedded Java.  Whether that is a security or not depends on what Bazel is actually doing.  A lot of Java security bugs are only seriously dangerous if the application is exposed outside of your machine; e.g. as a web server.

Answer (score 1):

I am not at all convinced that this is necessary.  (See my comments on the question.)

However if you really wanted to change Bazel's built-in Java you could take one of these approaches:

1. Follow the instructions in the [Contributing to Bazel](https://bazel.build/contributing.html) page.  Note that you need to install Bazel to build Bazel.  I am assuming that you get to choose (somehow) the Java that gets embedded in the "distributable" ... or that is downloaded by it, if that is what is happening.
2. There is a "compile.sh" file that *might* be an alternative.  (I didn't look too hard at it.)
3. You could probably download and install Bazel in the normal way and tweak the installation to replace the embedded Java with whatever you want.  For instance, try replacing its internal Java installation tree with a symlink to your system Java install that is kept up-to-date using the Linux package manager.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you are actually asking.  If you were really asking how to make sure that your "Local JDK" is up-to-date on Linux, that is simple.  1) Install it from the package manager, 2) run updates regularly, 3) after an update use the `alternatives` command to make sure that the version that you want is selected.  (Or update the `ABSOLUTE_JAVABASE` define in your `.bazelrc` file.  However, if you have set `ABSOLUTE_JAVABASE` to the right symlink, that becomes unnecessary.  Look at how `alternatives` works.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `--javabse` option in Bazel 2.0.0 (and also some other Bazel versions):

> --javabase (label) This option sets the label of the base Java installation to use for bazel run, bazel test, and for Java binaries
>   built by java_binary and java_test rules.

Just add a `.bazelrc` file alongside to your `WORKSPACE` file:

*.bazelrc*

```
build --javabase=//my_tools/my_own_jdk
```

Take also a look onto `java_runtime()`

Comment: Bazel has the ability to download and use a specific JDK version.  Isn't there some way to use that?