# Using the locally installed JDK for all Bazel operations

Tags: bazel

Normally Bazel downloads Java compilers from the internet and runs them to compile code. I am using Bazel in a restricted environment that doesn't allow running these downloaded binaries. I have an approved JDK v8 and Bazel installed locally. How do I configure Bazel to use this locally installed JDK for everything (running Bazel, compiling code, running tests, etc)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring bazel to build/test using a specific JVM version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040291/configuring-bazel-to-build-test-using-a-specific-jvm-version)

Comment: It's also documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040291/configuring-bazel-to-build-test-using-a-specific-jvm-version, and other info about running Bazel in an airgapped environment: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#running-bazel-in-an-airgapped-environment